# How to apply non-parametric methods to panel data? "The Elite Illusion: Achievment Effects at Boston and New York Exam Schools"

Tags: multiple-regression, panel-data, econometrics, nonparametric, regression-discontinuity

I'm studying this paper [The Elite Illusion: Achievment Effects at Boston and New York Exam Schools](http://www.nber.org/papers/w17264). There the authors use a fuzzy regression discontinuity design experiment to assess the ATE of going to an exame school. It seems that they use nonparametric methods like local linear/polynomial regression. I understand the applications when we are dealing only one dimension, and the formalization of the problem seems nice, like in this paper by [Imbens and Lemieux](http://www.nber.org/papers/w13039.pdf). However, in the Elite Illusion paper they apply nonparametric methods to panel data. I'm just not understanding how they do this? How would one formalize the $\min$ problem, and solve it?

Also, do you know of some nice introduction to the subject?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Looking at the parametric version formula (2), the panel data aspect is actually ignored, i.e. the data is pooled and estimated via 2SLS. The comment below equation (4) mentions that non-parametric estimate is calculated using kernel-weighted OLS. So this is not exactly classical non-parametric estimate. Again panel data aspect is ignored, i.e. data is pooled.

Comment: @mpiktas But if the panel aspect is ignored why do we have table 4 for estimates of the parametric and nonparametric, and then we also have estimates for 2SLS in table 6? Could you elaborate more, please? I''m new to this subject.

Comment: When I say that panel effect is ignored, I mean that model does not account for individual differences between students. Table 4 reports $\delta_{jk}$ from the model (2). The min problem was formalized, by stacking $y_{itk}$ into one long vector for each $k$. The relevant feature matrix is also stacked. This way you get ordinary regression problem $y=X\beta+\varepsilon$, where $y$ is a vector, $X$ is a matrix. The min problem is the formulated in the usual way. The same goes for non-parametric version, where non-parametric in the article means, that special weights are used.

Comment: I must note that panel effect is taken into account when standard errors are calculated, because authors mention, that they are clustered on student.